# Directory and subdirectory Filter in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, directory-listing

I need to list all directories from a path. I need to get only last subdirectory path and not all paths.

i.e. for

pathbase/2016/01

I don't need pathbase/2016 but pathbase/2016/01

Now I'm using this code:

```
List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(pathBase));
string[] entries = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(pathBase, "*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var listDir = from dir
              in entries

return listDir.ToList();
```

What type of filter can i use in Linq to exclude this directory?

Thanks.

Comment: So you need only leaf directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean you need all leafs directories (directories that don't have subdirectories)?

If so this should do it

```
// First off, don't use GetDirectories on the static Directory class, it returns a string path and not a DirectoryInfo which isn't very usefull here, instead create a DirectoryInfo and go from there:

var RootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(pathBase);
// Then queries all of it's subdirectories and filter on those
var listDir  = RootDirectory.GetDirectories("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(dir=>!dir.GetDirectories().Any())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: great. It's work. How I can get the name and the full path? I'm a newbie with linq. Thanks

Comment: @user1823851 you already have all of that, each element in listDir is a DirectoryInfo, it has all the properties you want unlike what you originally posted (which only returned strings). Don't forget to mark this as an answer if it answers your original question

Comment: @user1823851 next to the up and down arrow that are used to upvote there is a "V" you can click on to accept answer